# Localization not working

Tags: iphone, localization

I have an application that is supposed to be localized (two languages, english being the default).

However, I seem to only get the English versions of all strings, regardless of what the system default language is. I am probably missing something trivial, but I've read several tutorials now without any solution.

I added this line to main(),

```
NSLog(@"Current locale is: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
```

and the resulting printout is `en_US`, while the system was set to use the localized language.

I checked the build output, and the app bundle contains the XX.lproj folders as I believe they should (and they are UTF-16, I confirmed this).

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** It seems that my localization is working when I deploy the application through iTunes via a distribution certificate, but not when using XCode (Command-R or similar). Does anyone know what I am missing from my Debug configuration settings?

Comment: What exactly is `XX`? Should be ISO language codes, the language names (such as Spanish or Czech) don’t work anymore.

Comment: Yes they are ISO language codes (lowercase)

Comment: Update: I tried a device that has a non-English locale, and the current locale is then set correctly. The strings are still English though....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question and hopefully help others. My problem was solved by simply removing my application from the phone and reinstalling it from scratch. I had to do a complete remove (including all data), not just a clean+rebuild from Xcode.

I guess that the iPhone caches the available localizations somewhere...

Comment: In addition to that I'd recommend restarting Xcode, as after few times of clean up and remove I'm starting to get SIGABRT on loading the main nib. Above steps as regular actions and then xcode restart on those occasions seem to work 100%.

Comment: This is a quite old one, so forgive me if I remember something incorrectly, but I think that the problem was on the device, not in Xcode. That being said, I find that Xcode 4 needs it fair shares of restarts still...