# iOS localization strings AppStore

Tags: ios, string, localization, app-store

I have a question about the localization capability in iOS. My first version of my app (1.0) didn't used NSLocalizedString but my new 2.0 version uses it . I made everything correctly as explained there :
[Ios Localization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543025/ios-localization-not-working). I ran my app on the simulator and it worked great. Then I ran it on my device and nothing were working. I had the keys instead of the values showing up. I found this answer : [Localization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061334/localization-not-working). So I deleted my app from my device and re-install it and it worked. Here is the question.

Will it work directly when a user will download my app on the Appstore and more specific, when a user will update his 1.0 version? Will he have the values and not the keys without the need to delete and re-install the app? Does the installation/update from the Appstore make a clean installation on user's device?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Depends on how you use Localization. Updating the App will replace the App files itself, but won't explicitly delete old files saved in Documents.

Comment: Try it yourself. Delete your 2.0 build from your device. Then install the 1.0 version from the App Store. You now have what the user currently has. Now go back to Xcode and build and install 2.0 onto your device. This should essentially emulate what will happen for a user when they upgrade. Does the app work properly?

Comment: @Raptor : Thanks for your answer and yes the files no longer needed are deleted afterwards.

Comment: @rmaddy : I tried it and it worked. Thank you for your advice.